# History API is undefined by navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an app that uses an infinity scroll. Every time I reload data, I update the history.state with histroy.replaceState and the current number of pages. If I display the whole thing on the console, I don't see any errors, the new number of pages is output. However, if I navigate to another page and then back again, history.state is undefined or starts at 0 again. Why?
I use Chrome.
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state

```
const [page, setPage] = useState((history.state && history.state.page) || 0);

console.log("history.state.page " + history.state.page);

...

<SingleImage newLimit={() => {setPage(page + 11);history.replaceState({ page: page + 11 }, "");}} product={product}
    handleClickOnImageEvent={handleClickOnImageEvent}>
</SingleImage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with localStorage

```
// Save the current number pageNumberLocal
localStorage.setItem('pageNumberLocal', currentPageNumber);

// get pageNumberLocal
const savedPageNumber = localStorage.getItem('pageNumberLocal');

update starte using localstorage
if (savedPageNumber) {
  history.replaceState({ pageNumber: parseInt(savedPageNumber) }, '');
}

update the localStorage again before navigating
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('pageNumberLocal', currentPageNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state#value) that you referenced state the following:

> The value is null until the pushState() or replaceState() method is used.

Therefore on a page reload `history.state` will always be null.

One possible solution you could try is to use querystring params to hold your page state. e.g.

```
const url = new URL(location);
url.searchParams.set("page", page + 11);
history.replaceState({}, "", url);
```

example from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState#change_a_query_parameter